# If a NetLogo procedure contains more than one recursive call, how are they processed?

Tags: recursion, netlogo

In the models library there is this procedure in the Galton Box model.  Each time it is called, it makes two recursive calls, after a hatch to the left and a hatch to the right.

```
to propagate  ;; peg procedure
  if ycor < max-pycor - 2 - 2 * number-of-rows [ die ]
  set pcolor yellow
  set ycor ycor - 2
  hatch 1 [
    set xcor xcor - 1
    propagate
  ]
  hatch 1 [
    set xcor xcor + 1
    propagate
  ]
  die
end
```

Is there any guarantee of the order of the recursive calls to 'propagate'?  For example, does the first call (xcor - 1) complete entirely before the second (xcor + 1) begins?  Or does the initial call start the first, then start the second? Is there any guarantee which will finish first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely sequential. There is no parallelism or concurrency in NetLogo.

So yeah, the first call will complete entirely before the second starts.

This is from the Galton Box model, right? You can watch the recursion happen step by step as follows: switch the model from "tick-based updates" to "continuous updates", put the speed slider at a slow setting, then press the setup button. You'll see a strict left-to-right, depth-first traversal.